# Select with explode or other function content into 2 tags

Tags: php, explode

How i can using php separate this element i have into file

For example :

```
##cat 1##
**
element 1
element 2
element 3
**

##cat 2##
**
element 1
element 2
element 3
**

##cat 3##
**
element 1
element 2
element 3
**
```

I see during many time manual of php and i try explode , etc and no get good results , it´s possible with php send simple loop run all this content and separate in each case the content into ## or into ** and show each element separated ?

I try do this but something no well because i can´t do this and try many times with foreach , explode , bucle for , etc and always get the same result and show all no each element

Thank´s for the help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question. If you want to take the input above and produce the following:

```
Array
(
    [##cat 1##] => Array
        (
            [0] => element 1
            [1] => element 2
            [2] => element 3
        )

    [##cat 2##] => Array
        (
            [0] => element 1
            [1] => element 2
            [2] => element 3
        )

    [##cat 3##] => Array
        (
            [0] => element 1
            [1] => element 2
            [2] => element 3
        )
)
```

Try this:

```
$input_text =<<<INPUT_TEXT
##cat 1##
**
element 1
element 2
element 3
**

##cat 2##
**
element 1
element 2
element 3
**

##cat 3##
**
element 1
element 2
element 3
**
INPUT_TEXT;

$output = array();
$current = NULL;
foreach( explode( "\n", $input_text ) as $line )
{
    $line = trim( $line );
    if( empty( $line ) )
    {
        continue;
    }
    if( substr( $line, 0, 2 ) == '##' )
    {
        $current = trim( $line );
        continue;
    }
    if( substr( $line, 0, 2 ) == '**' )
    {
        continue;
    }
    if( !empty( $current ) )
    {
        $output[$current][] = $line;
    }
}
print_r( $output );
```

Comment: This content go into text file , the idea it´s separate each group and each date , in the case of "##" this indicate one category and into category i have the elements and these use other character for separate , the result must be this : Category 1 : elements 1 , 2 ,3 , Category 2 , elements 1 , 2 ,3 , ..... etc , Thank´s

Comment: Are you able to adapt my solution to your needs?  If not, would you post an example of *exactly* what you expect the output file to look like?